# In an image host script, how can I measure an image's bandwidth consumption?

Tags: php, image, bandwidth

I'm enhancing a PHP image hosting script, but I'm facing a problem: the client has requested a function to limit the amount of used bandwidth, for each image, to 100MB / day
This includes thumbnails

Up to now, thumbnails have been served directly without using PHP (with nginx)
I've tried using a php script instead of a direct .jpg, with a VERY heavily cached code (using APC's cache to store the amount of bandwidth used, and serving the image with the X-Sendfile header), but the server just chokes due to the very,very high amount of connections

Is there a more efficient way to measure bandwidth used by thumbnails without choking the CPU and RAM?
How is this problem usually tackled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse the server access logs. I believe in nginx they are at /var/log/nginx/access.log . You'll likely need to change permissions to allow access, or you could use cron to regularly copy that file into an accessible folder if you aren't comfortable doing that.

I guess that if you cached results, and only checked once an hour or something then you could do this using grep -c.

I'd be interested to know, if you pick a file you know has been accessed, how long does it take to run:

```
grep -c filename.jpg /var/log/nginx.access.log
```

You could then simply multiply that count by the filesize to get the bandwidth for that image.

Comment: The problem is that server access logs grow up to several hundred GB after a few hours..would that be feasible?

Comment: I've added a little more info above.

Comment: Actually when I send the grep command through console it just hands indefinitely. The access_log file is 800gb

Comment: grep is amazingly fast at what it does, so if that doesn't work, then using the logs in any way is going to be a problem. Short of serving up the image via a php script that increments a counter somewhere (which isn't a good idea - slow, dealing with locks etc) I can't see a good way to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to estimate how long it takes to reach 100MB? You could then just only allow access for a number of hours/minutes each day. Not accurate, but it would do the job.